# BigQuery SQL How to count the number of elements inside the Array

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We have a table in BigQuery that stored JSON data. I need to get the count of the changed array example below it contains a count of 14.

[image]

Expected Output is

Col_1 | Col_2

changed 14

Answer (score 1):

Use `ARRAY_LENGTH` function, e.g. `ARRAY_LENGTH(changed)`

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_length